# Different filter settings in report tabs of Google Analytics Custom Reporting?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm wondering if it's possible to have different filter settings in different report tabs of custom report in Google Analytics?

It looks like the filter settings can only be set for all report tabs of the custom report.

I'm trying to get 2 graphs

- 1 shows just home page visits (page exact = ***/***)
- 2 shows article page visits (page regex = ***/[Pp]age/.****)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have different filter settings in different report tabs of a custom report in Google Analytics.

You ***can***, however, create a Dashboard in the new Google Analytics interface that has a different filter applied to each widget.

I have created an example dashboard here. Browse to the GA profile you would like to add it to, then paste this link:

https://www.google.com/analytics/web/permalink?type=dashboard&uid=6p26M4W7SCWy0W1bFKvNSQ

It should create two widgets, one named 'Visits to home page' and the other named 'Visits to /[Pp]age/.*'. It's giving nice results for me - let me know if it works for you.

Comment: It's mind-boggling that you can't do this. I thought I was going crazy. Is this use-case so rare that perhaps I'm approaching the idea of custom reports wrong? I just wanted to view browser usage per month, with a different browser in each report tab.

Comment: One way you can have filters for each tab is, so long as you have the dimension set as a column, set the Advanced Filter and Save the configuration.  This is from the view mode ofr hte report, rather than the edit mode of the report.

Answer (score -3):

To use filters you first have to understand profiles.

Multiple profiles can be set up for single site AKA a single tracking code and a filter is used to filter data for 1 profile, a profile can have multiple types of filters but it'll still do something for only 1 profile. Also the filters are re-usable.

You can approach this question in several ways:

1. You can set up multiple profiles, each with it's own directory filter. However in GA you can't measure only the index site's traffic with clean urls.
2. You can set up advanced segments. This way you can easily compare statistics. But you still can't measure the index site's traffic if you've got clean urls.
3. See the Content -> Overview

Using the page exact match can result in some interesting side effects:

1. It'll show you the statistics of the WHOLE site, as / is the root of the page
2. Also it can show you the statistics of all the urls which has a / in it

Comment: -1. This post is answering a different question, and answering it incorrectly at that. The question is about the Custom Reports feature. Also, Page Exact Match doesn't behave the way you're describing at all. You might be confused with Advanced Segments, which query all the hits in a session that contains the condition you set, which is why filtering on the page value can lead to confusing results.

Comment: Sorry, but as far as I know there's only one place where GA allows regex, and that's the profiles section. Please go to your GA account, select a page, go to admin and there's the filter option which I was talking about. And in the end results using profiles or custom reports don't really differ.

Comment: That's not correct. There are many, many places that GA allows Regex. Advanced Segments, Report Filters (not to be confused with Profile Filters), Custom Reports, Goal Configurations, etc. Basically, any place that GA takes input as a string, it can be configured to allow for Regex.

Comment: You're still welcome to post the correct answer.

Comment: The first two paragraphs seem to be correct if OP is asking about applying 2 different profile-level profiles within a single custom report. If OP is asking about 2 different report-level profiles, I think the answer is "it's possible".